# Where i am wrong? A question on uniformly continuous function in functional analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Given metric spaces $(X, d) $ and $(Y, d') $ , a mapping $T:X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous on $X$ iff for every Cauchy sequence $(x_n) $ in $(X, d) $, the sequence $  (Tx_n) $ is Cauchy in $(Y, d') $.

One sided implication (uniformly continuous function map Cauchy sequence to Cauchy sequence) is easy to prove.

But what about the converse.

I think it is false.

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x) =x^2$$

maps Cauchy sequence to Cauchy sequence but this function is not uniformly continuous.

Please verify the proof that I upload as an image.

Is the proof correct?

[image: Please see the proof]

Comment: You cannot really claim $d(Tx_n,Tx_m)\gt r$ for *all* $m,n$ large; the lack of uniform continuity just means there will always be *some* $m,n$ that satisfy that

Comment: That's mean the proof is incorrect, sir.

Comment: Well, not really. If you amend “all” with “some”, you’ll be fine. Even having “some” contradictory $m,n$ breaks the Cauchy-ness of the sequence, which completes the proof

Comment: If the converse is true then what's going wrong  for the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by $f(x) =x^2$

Comment: How do you prove it maps Cauchy to Cauchy?

Comment: Sir, $(x_n) $ Cauchy in  $\mathbb{R}$ , then by completeness of $ \mathbb{R}$ , $(x_n) \to x \in  \mathbb{R}$ . By continuity of $f$ , $f(x_n) \to f(x) $ and every convergent sequence in $ \mathbb{R}$ Cauchy.

Comment: Where is the image from?

Answer (score 2):

The prove is wrong (and cannot be repaired). If $T$ is not uniformly continuous, there is $r>0$ such that for all $n$ there are two points $x_n,y_n$ with $d(x_n,y_n)<1/n$ and $d'(Tx_n,Ty_n)>r$. One cannot generate a Cauchy sequence out of these points, as $(x_n,y_n)$ and $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ are completely unrelated. This would only work if $(X,d)$ is compact